# How to do a WHERE statement with XPath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am working with [this XML](http://fiber.angelleye.com/temp/GetItemTransactionsResponse_231827718170.xml).  It's a string from an API response in my code, but I put it there for easy view.

You'll see it has a `<TransactionArray>` node with multiple `<Transaction>` nodes in it.  Right now I'm doing this to grab the `<TransactionID>` value out of the LAST node, regardless of how many there are.

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadXML($string);
$XPath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
$XPath->registerNamespace("ns","urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents");

$eBayTransIDs = $XPath->query("/ns:GetItemTransactionsResponse/ns:TransactionArray/ns:Transaction/ns:TransactionID/text()");
$eBayTransIDsLength = $eBayTransIDs->length;

if($eBayTransIDsLength > 0)
    $eBayTransID = $eBayTransIDs->item($eBayTransIDsLength - 1)->data;
else
    $eBayTransID = '';
```

This works as expected, which in most cases would be the most recent order, but it's not perfect logic and could cause a problem if two people purchase at the same time.  I need to be more precise.

Inside the `<Transaction>` nodes you will see `/ExternalTransaction/ExternalTransactionID` and I do have this value available in my code.  I cannot figure out how to specify that with XPath, though.

Basically, what I need is to "grab the `<Transaction>` node WHERE `/ExternalTransaction/ExternalTransactionID = $txn_id"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, two general notes:

- `WHERE` clauses roughly map to predicates within `[` and `]`.
- To inject an external variable value into the XPath, you can
  construct it from separate strings concatenated together.

Next then, to select the `Transaction` elements WHERE `ExternalTransaction/ExternalTransactionID = $txn_id`, use a concatenation of strings to form an XPath expression as follows:

```
"//Transaction[ExternalTransaction/ExternalTransactionID = '" + $txn_id + "']"
```

---

**Update** to add namespace prefixes and select string value of selected `ExternalTransactionID`:

```
"string(//ns:Transaction[ns:ExternalTransaction/ns:ExternalTransactionID = '" 
        + $txn_id 
        + "'])"
```